# How to include multiple plugins with next-css in next.config.js file

Tags: reactjs, webpack, next.js, react-slick

I am importing the react-slick css files. When i remove `cssModules:true` from next.config.js file, everything works fine. Any idea why adding `cssModules:true`  creates the problem?

```
const withCSS = require("@zeit/next-css");
module.exports = withCSS({
  cssModules: true,
  webpack: config => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.(eot|woff|woff2|ttf|svg|png|jpg|gif)$/,
      use: {
        loader: "url-loader",
        options: {
          limit: 100000,
          name: "[name].[ext]"
        }
      }
    });
    return config;
  }
});
```

Comment: I can' see the problem. Can you make a github repo where you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Don't really know the structure of your code but guess, you are importing the react-slick css file like this. 

`import css from "../style.css"`

If that's the case, you will need to change it to simply

`import  "../style.css"`

notice the lack of the string "css from" from the last import.

the first import style is what is causing the cssmodule effects to come into play and will therefore change the classnames and therefore, the slick component won't be appropriately selected by the slick.css files. If I may call it's css file slick.css.